# How to control what job offers are shown on the banners?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I've set C#, JS and such as my tags of interests. Java isn't there, no Ruby-on-whatever neither. Nevertheless, most of (and some days all of) the ads are about the non-tagged technologies. How can I control what's shown to be **inside** a certain job banner?

Comment: Related: [Is SO monitoring its users and adapting ads based on that?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270896)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until recently, you could not. The advertisements were only personalised towards your *location*, and your Stack Overflow favorite / ignored tags are not taken into account.

Recently, things have been improving however. Now advertisements are [targeted at specific tags and interests](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/), but the targeting is not customisable from the Stack Overflow user's end <sup>*</sup>.

If your Stack Overflow account is linked to your Careers account, then [adding tags to your *dislikes* field](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270620/how-to-control-what-job-offers-are-shown-on-the-banners/270622?noredirect=1#comment164987_270622) in your Careers profile will be used to filter out job ads shown to you on Stack Overflow; this gives you at least *some* control over what is being shown to you.

If you wanted to see new jobs in tags you *are* interested in, you can set up a RSS feed or email subscription instead. Go to the [Careers 2.0 homepage](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), set up a search, and use the icons at the top of the *search jobs* sidebar:

[image: search subscription options]

Otherwise, I'd just ignore the advertisement box. It is only in the sidebar, after all.

---

<sup>*</sup> Well, you can [opt out from the data collection](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) to stop all targeting. On that same page you can download the data set Stack Overflow has collected on you so you can see why you get certain job ads target at you.

Comment: I can tell you they are **not** localized to me. Unless we consider a commuter distance of 5000 kilometers, that is. One position was in New York (I'm in Stockholm) and it said "relocation" not "telecommuting". +1 for the extra info (although I'm not looking for a new job actively at the moment). However, I can point out that giving suggestion on Java positions for a C#-dude is like advertizing gay bars for a straight guy. Very unlikely to be of use. And occupies the attention that could've been devoted for something better.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I know where you are coming from; my Careers profile lists Java as an explicit dislike, keeps the recruiters at bay. Being located in the south-east of England, I am served with London positions all the time, but perhaps there is less choice around Stockholm and extra positions from around the world are added in to make up the numbers.

Comment: Hmm... I'm being approached by recruiters twice, three time a month. Stockholm is **very** hot area and nobody can find right people. So I think it's just a blunder in the algorithm. We've got great pay here and a lack of skilled professionals. On **any** platform, hehe. Maybe they're targeting worldwide and pay to SO for that exposure.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: perhaps; I tend to ignore the box in any case, so I may have missed the out-of-area posts quite easily.

Comment: Pragmatic approach. Darn effective, now that I think about it. One need not to improve every thing every time.   :)

Comment: "the targeting is not customisable from the Stack Overflow user's end" - then what is the point of these ads? Impressions? Would the CTR be about the same if the job ads *were* customizable, so the SO devs don't care about making that feature available?

Comment: @DanDascalescu: the point is to reach the people that are most likely to actually be interested in the jobs advertised. Also see [the data collected on you](http://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) to see what kinds of jobs might be targeted at you.

Comment: While full control is still a ways down the road, we've just started filtering out jobs that have tags that you have explicitly disliked on your Stack Overflow Careers profile, if you've linked your SO account with your Careers account

Comment: @rossipedia: cool, I'll keep updating the answers as changes come in. :-)