# Is SO monitoring its users and adapting ads based on that?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I have been fiddling with Net panel in Firebug and there are many requests one of which is interesting and is called `beacon.js`. that file doesn't disclose very much but it seems it's something targeted against every different user and I think ads better targeted to them.

Can someone with more knowledge chime in and explain what that is about, especially from the "other end"? If that turns to be true, is it possible to make the user acknowledged of the fact he's being monitored and targeted by ads other than `analytics.js`?

Comment: See the [privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy), specifically the *How We Collect Information* part. The implementation details don't matter here, do they?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I will take a look. I'm not sure. When it comes to the user they should know how their info are being handled. Not always the case if there are other policies already defined and clearly explained to the user just like in the privacy policy which I didn't see before.

Comment: I'm understanding that beacon.js is also part of SPAM monitoring from the privacy policy.

Comment: It is linked on every page, in the footer. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok :-) Guess I missed that because it in a brain lapsus somehow. I just read contact and a few others. Thank you again for your availability.

Comment: FWIW, the careers advertisements certainly take your location into account when selecting what to display. I see nothing but London positions.

Comment: Intriguing to say the least. I take that you're also from that place, so yeah.

Comment: Related: [Houston, we are web bugged!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210658/houston-we-are-web-bugged) on Meta SE

Comment: "and are representing that you have the right to transfer such information outside your country." Uuuuuugh.

Comment: I don't see any job offers at all. Guess I'm unemployable...:P

Comment: @MAGSHARE Weird! You should at least see something generally targeted to any U.S.A. state or maybe there's not enough data about you still..

Comment: I'm not sure if SO uses an ad network, but often the ad network is targeting ads based on other information they've collected outside of SO.  I've gone to other sites and/or searched and browsed certain server products and then noticed that exact product is being advertised to me on completely different sites. If an ad network is involved, alot of that is completely out of control of the site hosting the ad.

Comment: @Aaron: no ad network is involved; Adzerk provides the delivery service, Stack Exchange controls entirely what goes on and how targeting takes place.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Stack Exchange publishes a [Privacy Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) which includes a *How We Collect Information* section. It is linked from the footer on every page.

The implementation details don't really matter there and can and will change over time.

Advertisements are almost certainly adjusted based on that information. The Careers job ads in the sidebar take location into account, for example.

Recently, Stack Exchange has started to do more with the information they collect about frequent users. See [this blogpost](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow) for more details on how Careers advertisements are targeted, and you can download the information collected about you [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data).

Comment: I see positions from all over Australia. Sure, I want to apply for jobs 4000km away >_>

Comment: @sevenseacat I see a lot of offers for London/Germany jobs even though I live in the West side of France. It depends on the number of jobs actually available of Careers...

Comment: Regarding Careers, I see jobs from all over the world, but only in subjects I've posted in/read a lot questions on. In my case is PHP/Java/C#.

Comment: Hilarious but most of job ads come from `Sydney, Australia (relocation offered)`  even though I'm located in Turkey..

Answer (score 42):

Our Privacy Policy lays out how we track users (it's cookies, nothing crazy like [panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) or whatever).  I'll provide a little more insight here though.

We do adapt ads based on what we know about a user browsing Stack Overflow.  We *do not* share personally identifiable information with any of our advertisers, however.

Very very broadly, we target based on your location (this is really obvious) and then what we think would interest you.  Right now this is a very simple process, mostly based on the tags in the page.  Over time we've become more sophisticated (we used to do essentially no targeting), and I expect we will become more sophisticated still in the future.

For example, our homepage customization ML builds a profile of what tags you're interested in.  While this is currently *not* used for job ad selection purposes, I'm planning to start trying it out.

Generally speaking, when we think about ad targeting ideas:

- It must help keep ads relevant

  - We want clicks because of *interest* not trickery
- It must be built from our data

  - We're not interested in tracking users offsite

<strike>Something we don't have yet, but that I'm planning to build when our next ad overhaul is underway, is a page that lets you grab all the data we think we have about you.</strike>

There is now [a page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) that lets you see what our algorithms think, download the data, and disable the predictions if so desire.  We're still in the process of moving existing ML-y things to it; however, nothing **not in that download** is used for ad targeting.

Comment: Props for the last paragraph :)

Comment: As for planning, I see [that that is moving along nicely](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow).

Comment: As for http://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data: how to know to which site the ids in `QuestionViews` apply? (It's the same list for other sites, like http://superuser.com/users/prediction-data, but it seems only Stack Overflow questions are listed, right?)

Comment: @Arjan right now only Stack Overflow views are recorded, yes.