# Does the "Looking for a job?" widget follow a "profile-based algorithm"?

Tags: discussion

Or is it just random entries? I only ask this because I see irrelevant openings 70% of the time and that is quite significant.

For example, I'm from a PHP/MySql background, but the jobs I see in the widget include technologies like .Net, Ruby, Python, Java etc. Very rarely do I see an opening of my interest. Ruby, in particular, is in my list of ignored tags. So I have a feeling that it just shows a random list.

Or is it just that the widget isn't meant to be a "personalized" feature; and would show the same results to any visitor to the site.

Comment: Related: [Is SO monitoring its users and adapting ads based on that?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270896)

Comment: Ok, that clears the doubts that I had