# Stack Overflow Careers - How about linking the favorites to this?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So I see on the right hand side there's a nifty Stack Overflow Careers box.  Cool, I can dig a new job.  So I look at it and then notice, "Hey!  None of my "favorites" are in that box!"

[image]

So, I'm thinking, maybe it wouldn't be too difficult to link someone's favorites to what displays in the Careers box?  Sort of like, targeted careers.  It sure would make me click on that careers box a lot quicker, or directly on a job that displays one of my favorite tags.

Yay or Nay?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is SO monitoring its users and adapting ads based on that?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270896/is-so-monitoring-its-users-and-adapting-ads-based-on-that)

Comment: Quoting Kevin Montrose there: *Very very broadly, we target based on your location (this is really obvious) and then what we think would interest you. Right now this is a very simple process, mostly based on the tags in the page. Over time we've become more sophisticated (we used to do essentially no targeting), and I expect we will become more sophisticated still in the future.*

Comment: Also see [How to control what job offers are shown on the banners?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270620)