# Does SO Careers not know my location?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

According to the Answer to [this previous Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270620/how-to-control-what-job-offers-are-shown-on-the-banners), Careers ads in the sidebar are personalized only as to location.

However the sidebar ads I see are now for positions near Everett WA, pretty much the opposite side of the country from my residence.  It seems this behavior started a couple of months ago.  Perhaps there are no jobs listed now within 20 miles of my residence (there were a couple for a while), and the system then "defaults" to Everett WA?  (My residence location correctly displays in my profile in **stackoverflowcareers**.)

Comment: @KevinBrown:  Possibly.  We do have a handful of Questions tagged Careers here (thanks Anna!).

Comment: The Careers sidebar ad now correctly gives me a link to "more jobs near Knoxville TN...".

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134567/careers-adverts-on-stack-overflow

Comment: According to http://www.whatismyip.com/ my IP _is_ recognized as being from Germany (which is correct). However I only see job ads for the USA (which makes no sense at all). This started some weeks ago. I'm pretty sure that some months ago I did see only relevant jobs from Germany. This happens on my office computer as well as on my private computer at home.  Something _has_ changed