# Why aren't the "Looking for a job" ads customizable?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

The ["Looking for a job" panel can be removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285062/where-is-the-option-to-remove-looking-for-a-job), but [it can't be customized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270620/how-to-control-what-job-offers-are-shown-on-the-banners) and many users have reported that the job ads include even tags they've explicitly marked as "disliked" on Careers.

I also get jobs for tags I'm not interested in, and I'm located in Silicon Valley, which removes as a potential explanation the hypothesis that there weren't enough jobs matching my tags, so that other jobs had to fill in the ad.

Would it not increate the CTR to allow these ads to be customizable? How come that's not possible yet? Would the cost of work necessary to customize the ads not be offset by the CTR gains?

Comment: The new targeting features are *very, very new* and those *placing* the job ads have to explicitly opt in too. That means that the current majority of advertisements are simply not targeted. Targeted ads for specific tags are actually very clearly marked; you'll recognise one when you see it.

Comment: I just opened a page and was served an advertisement for [tag:python] jobs: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hOtA6.png. If you are not seeing such clear marking, it is probably not a targeted job ad.

Comment: Last but not least, [look over the dataset Stack Overflow holds on you](http://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data); see if anything odd sticks out on that.

Comment: See related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249745/personalization-of-careers-advertisements

Comment: @MartijnPieters those tag-themed ads are an experiment we're currently running. They're only for java, python, and c#, and we only show them if one of those tags are in your top 5 tags, and every job in the ad has that tag... and only 50% of the time that all of that criteria matches (the other half is a control group). Not seeing a creative like that doesn't indicate the ad wasn't targeted. However, there is some randomness in the algorithm, and location is still the biggest influencer.

Comment: @BretCopeland: ah, my mistake for making assumptions those were the targeted ads.

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible yet quite simply because we haven't gotten there yet.

Previously, the job listings in that side panel were served from code in the main Careers application. Last year we created a dedicated team to build a new application for serving those listings, and to pave the way for much more relevant and intelligent job ads. It was a bumpy road, and we took a few wrong turns (and learned quite a bit along the way), but we eventually built a platform that gives us a strong foundation for moving forward.

Part of that intelligence is the (extremely) new [Providence](http://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/) project, which provides much better matching between visitors and job listings. But that's just a start. We have quite a few ideas in the pipeline for serving those job listings better, but we know that ads are a touchy subject for many users, so we want to do it *right*.

Ultimately, we just want to help programmers find better jobs.

**EDIT**: We are now filtering out jobs that have tags that you have explicitly disliked on your Stack Overflow Careers profile. It's a baby step, but it's in the right direction.